# TypeScript Type Definitions for SharePoint 2010 CSOM (JavaScript) and MicrosoftAjax.js

Tags: sharepoint, typescript, csom

Do type definition files exist for SharePoint 2010 JavaScript files such as SP.JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Our library can generate Typescript for Sharepoint 2010, not sure about 2013. It is quite new so the most info about it can be found in this error report :) but this error has been fixed since then (please use the latest from git).

- https://github.com/jaydata/jaydata/issues/55
- https://gist.github.com/3972900

We'll have a blogpost about this soon.

Answer (score 2):

Just released http://sptypescript.codeplex.com/

Most definitions are suitable for SharePoint 2010

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the hours that have gone by since you asked this question I would guess no. But feel free to write one yourself.  Its pretty simple and easy. Just start with the functions you know and use, and then keep extending it.